# Retrieve data for a particular date and 7days ago value using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[image]

I want to extract  data for a mentioned date  and 7 days prior data together in pandas.
Trying to automate the 7  days earlier part but unable to do so using
`dt.timedelta(days=7)`.

Result:
How i want it:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please post your data as text and not as an image. This also makes it much easier for users to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Are your column names actual datetime values, or strings? `dt.timedelta()` will only work if they are actual datetime values. What code did you try and what is the error or outcome that you get?

Answer (score 0):

In your example the date 7 days earlier is 6 days earlier...  All works fine,  I've created reproducible version of DF as a transpose for simplicity.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dr = pd.date_range(dt.date(2020,6,25),dt.date(2020,7,8))
df = pd.DataFrame({
"dotdate":dr,
    "impressions":np.random.randint(200000,400000, len(dr)),
    "impressions":np.random.randint(200000,400000, len(dr)),
    "link_clicks":np.random.randint(200000*150,400000*150, len(dr)),
})

df = df.set_index("dotdate").T
mydate = dt.date(2020,7,7)
df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c==mydate or c==(mydate-pd.Timedelta(days=7))]]
```

|  | 2020-06-30 00:00:00 | 2020-07-07 00:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| impressions | 274529 | 247155 |
| link_clicks | 4.61249e+07 | 3.26222e+07 |